# ¿Cómo hacer redirect en allauth usando django/python?

Tags: python, django

Estoy trabajando con Python y Django.
Tengo un registro/login manual y, por otro lado, instalé el registro/login de Gmail.

Al loguearse en forma manual, se ejecuta la función dashboard según el id del usuario, por ejemplo "http://127.0.0.1:8000/dashboard/9" y tiene diferentes opciones para seguir relacionadas con su id de usuario:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por su parte, en relación a Gmail, logro que el usuario se registre y loguee a través de Gmail, pero al momento de loguearse, va a la url http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/google/login/callback/?(...)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Entiendo que debería crear un redirect y/o una vista dentro de la app social_app que genera allauth para que vaya a "dashboard/id", pero estoy perdido sobre cómo hacerlo, alguna idea? Gracias!